# How to remove horizontal grid from sphere pspicture

Tags: diagrams, pst-solides3d

Here is what I have so far:

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\usepackage{pst-solides3d}

\begin{document}

\psset{Decran=20,viewpoint=40 20 20 rtp2xyz,lightsrc=viewpoint,action=draw**,
       fillcolor=blue!30!white,linewidth=0.1pt}
\psset{incolor=red!60!white}

\begin{pspicture}(-1.5,-1)(1.5,3)
\psSolid[object=sphere,r=3,ngrid=20 20,hollow](0,0,2)
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

I would like to remove all the horizontal lines from the grid, and leave only the vertical ones. For example:

[image]

Comment: If this is the exact your question in http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/269959/how-to-draw-longitude-lines-on-sphere, please consider to delete this post.

Comment: @CroCo This question was for a solution using the pst-solides3d package, and the other one you linked was for a solution using TiKz