# How to draw longitude lines on sphere

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

Here is what I have so far:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\fill[ball color=blue!20] (0,0) circle (1.5 cm);
\newcommand\longitude[1]{%
  \draw (#1:1.5) arc (0:-180:{1.5*cos(#1)} and {0.2*cos(#1)});
  \draw[dashed] (#1:1.5) arc (0:180:{1.5*cos(#1)} and {0.2*cos(#1)});
}
\longitude{30};
\longitude{0};
\longitude{-30};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

But this draws latitudinal lines instead of longitudinal lines. I am aiming for the diagram to look like this:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[TeXample.net](http://www.texample.net) can be a good resource. Here is something adapted from the [Dandelin Spheres](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/dandelin-spheres/) example.

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{
    MyPerspective/.style={scale=1.8,x={(-1cm,0cm)},y={(1cm,0cm)},
    z={(0cm,1.2cm)}}
        }
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[MyPerspective]
        \foreach \t in {0,15,...,165}% meridians
            {\draw[gray] ({cos(\t)},{sin(\t)},0)
                \foreach \rho in {5,10,...,360}
                    {--({cos(\t)*cos(\rho)},{sin(\t)*cos(\rho)},
          {sin(\rho)})};
            }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]